# How to prevent useEffect() run twice after running a function in context consumer and prevent useContext() to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm learned that React will re-render after state changed e.g. `setState` from `useState()`, calling the function or variable from `useContext()` variable. But now I'm don't understand that why I get the `ESLint` warning call the context function inside the `useCallback()` without dependency in the list. If I put the dependency in the list, `useCallback()` will be re-rendered and `useEffect()` dependency from `useCallback()` variable will do again. So how to fix the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` when calling the function inside the `useContext()` variable?

Auth.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import * as AuthAPI from "../API/AuthAPI"
import Loading from "../Page/Loading"

const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

  const [user,setUser] = useState()
  const [loadingInitial,setLoadingInitial] = useState(true)

  useEffect(()=>{
    AuthAPI.getCurrentUser()
    .then((user)=>setUser(user))
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
    .finally(()=>setLoadingInitial(false))
  },[])

  const login = async (email,password) => {
    const user = await AuthAPI.login({email,password})
    setUser(user)
    return user
  }

  const register = async (firstname,lastname,email,password) => {
    const user = await AuthAPI.register({firstname,lastname,email,password})
    setUser(user)
    return user
  }

  const logout = async () => {
    const response = await AuthAPI.logout()
    setUser(undefined)
  }

  const value = useMemo(()=>({
      user,
      setUser,
      login,
      register,
      logout
  }),[user])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {loadingInitial ? <Loading/> : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Logout.js

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../Hooks/Auth";
import * as AuthAPI from "../API/AuthAPI"
import Loading from "./Loading";

function Logout() {
  const auth = useAuth()
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const [isLoggedOut,setIsLoggedOut] = useState(false)

  const logout = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("Logging out!")
    await AuthAPI.logout()
    auth.setUser((prevState)=>(undefined))
    setIsLoggedOut(true)
  },[auth]) // --> re-rendered because `auth` context in re-rendered when set `user` state.

  useEffect(()=>{
    logout()
  },[logout]) // --> this also to run again from `logout` callback is being re-rendered.

  if (!isLoggedOut) {
    return <Loading/>
  }

  return (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace/>
  )
}

export default Logout
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you import the useCallback? ie: (import React, { useCallback } from 'react';)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake at code section. Actually, I'm already imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about destructuring your auth context, since you are only using setUser inside useEffect?

```
const { setUser } = useAuth()

useEffect(() => {

....
}, [setUser])
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. `useEffect()` is run at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for creating a memoized `logout` callback function if `logout` isn't used/passed as a callback function. Just apply the logging out logic in the `useEffect` hook.

Render the `Loading` component and issue the imperative redirect from the resolved Promise chain of the return `AuthAPI.logout` Promise.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../Hooks/Auth";
import * as AuthAPI from "../API/AuthAPI"
import Loading from "./Loading";

function Logout() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Logging out!");
    AuthAPI.logout()
      .then(() => auth.setUser(undefined))
      .finally(() => navigate("/login", { replace: true }));
  }, []);
    
  return <Loading />;
}
    
export default Logout;
```

Comment: Should I worry about `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning?

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai Only if you want this component to remain mounted and potentially invoke the hook callback more than once. From what I can tell it's likely complaining about `auth` and `navigate` being dependencies. Since you only want the effect to run once when the component mounts, using an empty dependency array is the correct use case. There might not be any issue though with adding `auth` as a dependency though since the `auth.setUser(undefined))` and `navigate` action happen in the same render cycle, this component will be unmounted prior to the auth state/context changing.

Comment: @PaweenwatManeechai If you leave the dependency array empty then you can disable the lint rule for *that* specific line, add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` on the line above the dependency array in the `useEffect` hook. I suggest also adding a comment explicitly explaining why you are overriding any established linting rules for the project so future you or anyone looking at the code later understands clearly why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace your useEffect code into this:
useEffect(logout, [])

Comment: I recieved an error `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'logout'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` instead.